# Regular expression to match capture group not preceded by certain characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to write a regex that will match if and only if the pattern is not preceded by the characters "Etc/".

Strings that should match:

```
GMT+01:00
UTC+01:00
UTC+01
+01:00
...
```

Strings that should **not** match:

```
Etc/GMT+01:00
Etc/UTC+01:00
Etc/UTC+01
...
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<!Etc\/)((UTC|GMT)?(\+|\-){1}(\d{1,2})(:|\.)?(\d{1,2})?)
```

The right part of the above regular expression already matches the UTC and GMT offset and covers all the cases I need. But I don't manage to implement the exceptions mentioned above.
I expected the above regex to not match the string `Etc/GMT+1:00`. But in fact it matches the part `+01:00` and only ignores `Etc/GMT`.

How can I achieve that the the following regular expression does not match if it is preceded with "Etc/"?

```
(UTC|GMT)?(\+|\-){1}(\d{1,2})(:|\.)?(\d{1,2})?
```

[Here](http://regexr.com/5sd37) I have an example with most of the use cases I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add `\S*` after `Etc/` to make sure `Etc/` is checked even if there are any zero  or more non-whitespace chars between `Etc/` and the expected match:

```cs
(?<!\bEtc/\S*)((UTC|GMT)?([+-])(\d{1,2})[:.]?(\d{1,2})?)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CbEtc%2F%5CS*%29%28%28UTC%7CGMT%29%3F%28%5B%2B-%5D%29%28%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%29%5B%3A.%5D%3F%28%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%29%3F%29&i=Should%20match%3A%0D%0ASome%20text%20%28UTC%2B01%3A00%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0A%28UTC%2B01%3A00%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0AUTC%2B01%3A00%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0AUTC%2B1%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0A%2B01%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0A-01%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0ASome%20text%20%28UTC%2B01%3A00%29Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0ASome%20text%20%2B01%3A00Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%0D%0AAmsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%2B01%0D%0AAmsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20ViennaGMT%2B01%0D%0AAmsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%20UTC%2B01%0D%0AAmsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna%20%28GMT%2B01%29%0D%0AUTC%2B01%3A00%0D%0AUTC%2B01%0D%0AGMT%2B01%3A00%0D%0AUTC%2B01%0D%0AUTC-01%0D%0AUTC%2B1%0D%0AUTC%2B1%3A%0D%0A%2B1%0D%0A-1%0D%0A%2B01%3A00%0D%0A-1%3A0%0D%0AGMT%2B1000%0D%0A%28GMT%2B01.00%29%20Sarajevo%2FWarsaw%2FZagreb%0D%0A%0D%0AShould%20not%20match%3A%0D%0AEtc%2FGMT%2B1%0D%0AEtc%2FGMT%2B01%3A00%0D%0ASome%20text%20%28Etc%2FUTC%2B01%3A00%29%20Amsterdam%5C%2C%20Berlin%5C%2C%20Bern%5C%2C%20Rome%5C%2C%20Stockholm%5C%2C%20Vienna)

*Details*:

- `(?<!\bEtc/\S*)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a whole word `Etc/` and then zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `(UTC|GMT)?` - an optional substring, `UTC` or `GMT`
- `([+-])` - `+` or `-`
- `(\d{1,2})` - one or two digits
- `[:.]?` - an optional `:` or `.`
- `(\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of one or two digits (equal to `(\d{0,2})`).

Answer (score 0):

As you are already capturing all data in groups, another way could be getting all the matches of `Etc/` out of the way, and use your pattern to capture what you want in the groups.

Note that you can change groupings of single chars like `(:|\.)` to a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `([:.])`

```
\bEtc/\S*|(UTC|GMT)?([+-])(\d{1,2})([:.])?(\d{1,2})?
```

- `\bEtc/\S*` Match `Etc/` and optional non whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `(UTC|GMT)?([+-])(\d{1,2})([:.])?(\d{1,2})?` Your pattern with all the separate groups.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNrstl/1)

Or with just a single group:

```
 \bEtc/\S*|((?:GMT|UTC)?\+\d{2}(?:[:.]\d{2})?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eCRlyI/1)